# couldnt save current locked by another user

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

When i trying to browse and choose some image into picture box and then i click update button

it's error message pop up and display couldnt be save current locked by another user.

```
If lblTable.Text = "Visitor_ApplyPass" Then
    Dim fsr As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Using br As New BinaryReader(fsr)
        Dim imgbuffer(fsr.Length) As Byte
        br.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsr.Length)
        fsr.Close()
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=..\VisitorPass.accdb")
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "Update " & lblTable.Text & " set Visitor_Name='" & txtName.Text & "',[Visitor_Photo]= @imgfile where [VisitorApply_ID]=" & lblID2.Text & ""

            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgfile", imgbuffer)

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("profile is updated")
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Me.Close()
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you are updating the record in both DAO (the form) and ADO in the code above. This is two different users.

Comment: Side note: `"Update " & lblTable.Text & " set Visitor_Name='" & txtName.Text & "'` should be parameterized as it opens your app up to an sql injection attack.